# How to pass values to SOAP service using web service consumer?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Hello i have an soap service , in which a method will receive 2 input values and gives a bool O/P.
i am using web service consumer endpoint to consume this soap service. i want to understand what is the way i can send values to SOAP service .

```html
`<ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" wsdlLocation="http://.....?singleWsdl" service="ClientService" port="WSHttpBinding_IClientService" serviceAddress="http://....../ClientService.svc" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
<ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="AuthenticateUser" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based of the web service consumer [documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Web+Service+Consumer), the consumer is expecting the xml request of the service operation.

My quick suggestion is to use any tool to build the **xml request** based on the wsdl (such as **SOAP UI**) and use it in a **set-payload**, using MEL expressions to inject the two parameter values.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

The web service consumer is very tipically used in conjunction with DataMapper, with it datamapper can pretty much visually construct a request for you. Given that DataMapper is an EE feature and you don't mention you have a license I suggest you changing approach and rather use the [CXF module](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Consuming+Web+Services+with+CXF).

Answer (score 1):

Please go through to get a better understanding on **ws:consumer** :- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Web+Service+Consumer+Reference  and http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Web+Service+Consumer 
also there is an example in github:-   https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-tooling-examples/blob/master/web-service-consumer/src/main/app/tshirt-service-consumer.xml

You can use `<stdio:inbound-endpoint system="IN" doc:name="STDIO"/>` to pass values to the service .. But I am not sure if it is a recommended approach ..
Another option is **set-payload** you can try to pass the value to the service

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with this example

```html
  <ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" 
 
 
         wsdlLocation="somelocation_1.0.wsdl" 
 
 
         service="GreeterResponderService" port="GreeterResponderPort" 
 
 
         serviceAddress="http://user:password@localhost:8088/mockbinding" 
 
 
         doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
```